# Why am I getting this error when I run 'mup deploy': "build: You're not in a Meteor project directory"?

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, compose-db

I'm attempting to deploy a meteor app to Digital Ocean and Compose.io and am getting this error when I run `mup deploy`:

`build: You're not in a Meteor project directory.`

I *am* in the meteor project directory.

Answer (score 8):

For those running into this issue, make sure the "app" parameter is correctly set to the location of your meteor app. This solved the problem.